# Django FileField default file

Tags: django, django-models, default-value, filefield

I have a model which contains `FileField` as below

```
class Employer(models.Model):
        logo = models.FileField(storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT), upload_to='logos')
```

The question is how can I add a default file like "{{ MEDIA_ROOT}}/logos/anonymous.jpg" to this filefield ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can specify the default file to use for that field as follows:

```
class Employer(models.Model):
        logo = models.FileField(storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT), upload_to='logos', default='settings.MEDIA_ROOT/logos/anonymous.jpg')
```

Comment: how does the default parameter `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` get interpolated to the proper value in the string?

Comment: the path django is going to use in default is (by default): settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + 'your_path', so be sure you place your default file there

Comment: Don't think this solution scales across environments? If the production instance runs S3, for example, does something like `MEDIA_ROOT` work? And I think the hardcoded `FileSystemStorage` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

in your models file

```
logo = models.FileField(upload_to='logos', default='logos/logo.png')
titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

in your settings add

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
MEDIA_URL = '/logos/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution above was not really working for me (settings.MEDIA_ROOT is not beeing interpreted and I want to gitignore the media folder) here's a (somehow hacky) solution which allows me to specify a static file as a default in an Image/FileField:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="image/", default='..{}img/dashboard/default-header.jpg'.format(settings.STATIC_URL),
                          verbose_name=_(u'image'))
```

The hacky part is that if you have a MEDIA_URL with more than one level '..' won't be enough (but then you can simply go with '../../').