# Default image in django model File Field?

Tags: python, django

I want a default picture in the model file field, my code is not working. The file field is empty.

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='team_icons', null='True', blank='True', 
default='pictures/picture.png')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django FileField default file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740715/django-filefield-default-file)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageField` for storing images in objects and `FileField` to save them.

in your model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_tp='team_icons', null=True, blank=True)
```

if your form:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = models.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: i understand, but is it possible to realise this directly in de model field.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want to store an image there's a perfectly working  field for it, just use it.

Comment: because i dont want to rewrite the app. I can handle it in swift but i would be nicer if there was an easy way in django.

Comment: It wont take long, just change the field and migrate. By the way it could be that your `null='True', blank='True'` are causing an error because these arguments don't accept parameters in braces but boolean values, i.e. you should write it like `null=True, blank=True`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the default image with `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` base path. `MEDIA_ROOT` is absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='team_icons', null='True', blank='True', 
default='settings.MEDIA_ROOT/pictures/picture.png')
```

Also make sure that image exist at that path.